# JSOUP check if element is img

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have an object Elements xxx. 
Now I want to iterate over it and I would like to check if any element is `img` tag. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `tagName`:

```
Elements yourElements = ...

for( Element element : yourElements )
{
    if( element.tagName().equals("img") == true)
    {
        // It's an 'img'
    }
    else
    {
        // It's not an 'img'
    }
}
```

Comment: yea, I solved it already :) but will mark your answear for good :) I made something similar :)

Comment: Great! Just make sure you use *always lowercase* names; jsoup handles all tagnames LC.

Comment: Alternatively, you use `equalsIgnoreCase()` and don't have to worry about Jsoup's tag name representation.